# Extracting values from nested object and outputting their keys according to a rule (3 minimal values) in a certain format

Tags: javascript

I have an object with some nested data that I need to process programmatically to achieve a certain output. It will be the easiest to explain by demonstrating with example.

*Example*

I conducted an experiment and measured speed of dogs and cats running. I gathered the data in the following `groups` object. We can see two major categories for each group, i.e., `dogs` and `cats`. Then, in each group, we have one property about the mean average speed time of the group members, as well as `individuals` object that holds the data about each group member.

```js
const groups = {
  dogs: {
    groupMeanRecord: 11.7,
    individuals: {
      lassie: {
        record: 10,
        age: 2,
      },
      slinky: {
        record: 13,
        age: 4,
      },
      toto: {
        record: 11.5,
        age: 1,
      },
      marley: {
        record: 15,
        age: 1,
      },
      beethoven: {
        record: 9,
        age: 13,
      },
    },
  },
  cats: {
    groupMeanRecord: 7.75,
    individuals: {
      grumpyCat: {
        record: 6,
        age: 4,
      },
      salem: {
        record: 9,
        age: 11,
      },
      garfield: {
        record: 5,
        age: 3,
      },
      kitty: {
        record: 11,
        age: 10,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I want to figure out who are the animals, in each group, whose `record` values are the lowest. I decided that I want the 3 lowest in each group. Hence, my desired output, given this current data, is:

```js
const desiredOutput = {
  dogs: 'beethoven, lassie, toto',
  cats: 'garfield, grumpyCat, salem',
};
```

---

*my attempt*

Below is the code that I was able to come up with and it does give the desired output. However, as I'm new to JavaScript, I *believe* that there has to be an easier/more straightforward way to do this.

- **step 1** – clean up the data to get just what I need

  ```js
  const cleanDataArrOfArrs = Object.entries(groups).map(
    ([group, groupData]) => [
      group,
      Object.entries(groupData.individuals).map(([individual, data]) => [
        individual,
        data.record,
      ]),
    ]
  );
  //   [
  //     'dogs',
  //     [
  //       ['lassie', 10],
  //       ['slinky', 13],
  //       ['toto', 11.5],
  //       ['marley', 15],
  //       ['beethoven', 9],
  //     ],
  //   ],
  //   [
  //     'cats',
  //     [
  //       ['grumpyCat', 6],
  //       ['salem', 9],
  //       ['garfield', 5],
  //       ['kitty', 11],
  //     ],
  //   ],
  // ]
  ```
- **step 2** – I want to make the result of step 1 an object of objects

  - utilizing this helper function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63810699/6105259)

    ```js
    const makeObject = (arr) => {
      return Object.fromEntries(
        arr.map(([key, val]) =>
          Array.isArray(val) ? [key, makeObject(val)] : [key, val]
        )
      );
    };
    ```
  - calling `makeObject()` on `cleanDataArrOfArrs`

    ```js
    const cleanDataObj = makeObject(cleanDataArrOfArrs)
    // {
    //   dogs: { lassie: 10, slinky: 13, toto: 11.5, marley: 15, beethoven: 9 },
    //   cats: { grumpyCat: 6, salem: 9, garfield: 5, kitty: 11 },
    // };
    ```
- **step 3** – now I want to sort `cleanDataObj.dogs` and `cleanDataObj.cats` properties from lowest to largest (respectively).

  - utilizing a helper function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37607084/6105259):

  ```js
  const sortObj = (o) =>
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));
  ```

  - and finally:

  ```js
  const myOutput = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(cleanDataObj).map(([k, v]) => [
      k,
      Object.keys(sortObj(v)).slice(0, 3).join(', '),
    ])
  );
  // {
  //   dogs: 'beethoven, lassie, toto',
  //   cats: 'garfield, grumpyCat, salem',
  // };
  ```

---

My worry is that this code, although working, is neither readable nor addressing the task properly, and that there might be a much simpler way to approach this. I'd therefore be happy to learn how such a task could be otherwise done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method
const getIndNames = obj => (
  Object.entries(obj)                   // iterate over key-value pairs
  .map(([k, v]) => ({name: k, ...v}))   // get an array of objects with 'name', 'record', 'age' props
  .sort((a, b) => a.record - b.record)  // sort the array descending order of record
  .filter((_, idx) => (idx < 3))        // filter to retain top 3
  .map(({name}) => name)                // extract just the 'name' prop
  .join(', ')                           // use '.join' to generate a comma-separated string
);

// method that iterates over each group (cats, dogs)
const fastestThree = obj => (
  Object.fromEntries(                     // convert the final-result back into object
    Object.keys(obj).map(                 // iterate over key-value pairs of 'obj'
      k => ([                             // for each key, return an array of 2 elements
        [k],                              // first is the key 'k' itself
        getIndNames(obj[k].individuals)   // second is the fastest-three cats/dogs
      ])
    )
  )
);

// data from the question
const groups = {
  dogs: {
    groupMeanRecord: 11.7,
    individuals: {
      lassie: {
        record: 10,
        age: 2,
      },
      slinky: {
        record: 13,
        age: 4,
      },
      toto: {
        record: 11.5,
        age: 1,
      },
      marley: {
        record: 15,
        age: 1,
      },
      beethoven: {
        record: 9,
        age: 13,
      },
    }
  },
  cats: {
    groupMeanRecord: 7.75,
    individuals: {
      grumpyCat: {
        record: 6,
        age: 4,
      },
      salem: {
        record: 9,
        age: 11,
      },
      garfield: {
        record: 5,
        age: 3,
      },
      kitty: {
        record: 11,
        age: 10,
      },
    },
  }
};

// invoke the method and print the result
console.log(fastestThree(groups));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments in the above code-snippet explain the significant aspects of the solution.